# Deleting empty columns with a few columns between data

Tags: python, pandas, emptydatatext

I'm fetching data from a Google sheet:

```
values1 = pd.DataFrame(values)
aux = values1.head(1)
values1.drop(index={0}, inplace=True)
senal1 = (values1[2] == "SEÑAL")
senal = values1[senal1]
senal.dropna(axis=1, inplace=True)
print(senal)
```

This is my result after running the code:

[image]

Comment: This is what I'm getting 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oza9N.png

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO. I [fixed the question formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71543417/revisions). I think the result is included now. I think your initial data set and the expected result aremissing.

Comment: Try `senal.dropna(axis=1, thresh=len(senal[0]), inplace=True)`